# Rails 4 ActionController::UnknownFormat format.js error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a search form on a users page

```
= form_tag(action: 'search', remote: true ) do
    = date_field_tag 'start'
    = submit_tag "Find"
```

When I submit the form, I get the following error:

```
406 Not Acceptable in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)

    ActionController::UnknownFormat - ActionController::UnknownFormat:
      actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:219:in `respond_to'
      app/controllers/users_controller.rb:40:in `search'
```

My controller action is:

```
def search
    puts  params
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
end
```

I have a search.js.erb file that just prints to the console.

I can't figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: I think you need to specify format like `action: 'search.js'`

Comment: What is the request format generated in the server log?

Comment: @Pavan `Processing by UsersController#search as HTML`

Comment: That says it, The request format is `HTML` not `JS`. Your code is fine, just make sure you have Javascript running in your app.

Comment: I do have javascript running, other controllers can respond to js, I don't know what the problem is

Comment: @raphael_turtle - could you try this `= form_tag('/search', remote: true ) do`. Notice the syntax!

Comment: @raphael_turtle Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the method `form_tag` wrong way. If you specify `action` in `form_tag`, you must specify those in different hashes.

```
= form_tag( { action: 'search' }, { remote: true } ) do
```

And this is the reason that why you were getting request as an HTML request, instead of a JS request.

You will have to be explicit telling `form_tag` that you are sending `action: 'search'` for `url_for_option` hash, and `remote: true` for `options` hash.

Here's the method signature:

```
form_tag(url_for_options = {}, options = {}, &block)
```

For more information, head over to [`form_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag).